# Ho do I split these 2 string using Regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

Following are 2 strings:

```
"    at callback (/Users/lem/Projects/RingAPI/packages/server/node_modules/loopback-connector-rest/lib/rest-builder.js:541:21)"

"    at /Users/lem/Projects/RingAPI/packages/server/node_modules/@loopback/repository/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/observer.js:269:22"
```

How do I split them to these using JS and Regex?

```
['callback', '/Users/lem/Projects/RingAPI/packages/server/node_modules/loopback-connector-rest/lib/rest-builder.js', '541', '21']

['', '/Users/lem/Projects/RingAPI/packages/server/node_modules/@loopback/repository/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/observer.js', '269', '22']
```

Comment: Split string at `:` first. Then match `/ \/.*/` in first part. And later simply check if there is `callback` in first part

Answer (score 1):

I've wrote simple parse function for you:

```js
function parse(string) {
  const functionName = string.match(/at .* /);
    return [
      ...(functionName && [functionName[0].slice(2).trim()] || ['']),
      ...string.match(/\/.*/)[0].split(':')
    ];
}
```

First of all I try to extract function name. If it exists I remove 'at' word and use trim function to remove unnecessary spaces. Then I look for substring beginning with slash '/' and match every character after it. Last step is to split returned string.

I believe it matches your requirements.
I've also prepared demo in stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-ol22yf

Comment: Hi, the 'callback' is only an example, it might be 'MyClassName.myMethod'

Comment: I've edited my answer and stackblitz demo

Answer (score 1):

### try regexp named groups

https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-named-groups

it adds result readability for such strange regexes ;)

```js
const strings = [
    "    at callback (/Users/lem/Projects/RingAPI/packages/server/node_modules/loopback-connector-rest/lib/rest-builder.js:541:21)",
    "    at /Users/lem/Projects/RingAPI/packages/server/node_modules/@loopback/repository/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/observer.js:269:22"
];

const regex = /^\s*?at\s?(?<source>.*?)\s\(?(?<path>.*?):(?<row>\d*):(?<column>\d*)/;

strings.forEach(string => {
    const result = string.match(regex);
    resultElement.innerHTML +=
        '\n' + JSON.stringify({string, "result.groups": result.groups}, null, 4)
})
```

```html
<pre id="resultElement"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex for such purpose, i.e:

```
    const regex = /at( (?:[a-z]+)?)\(?(.+)\:(\d+)\:(\d+)\)?/;
    //const str = "    at callback (/Users/lem/Projects/RingAPI/packages/server/node_modules/loopback-connector-rest/lib/rest-builder.js:541:21)";
    const str = "    at /Users/lem/Projects/RingAPI/packages/server/node_modules/@loopback/repository/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/observer.js:269:22";
    const found = str.match(regex);
    found.splice(0, 1)
    console.log(found)
```

It works for both strings!

Comment: Can you return an empty string if there is no function or method name?

Comment: You can check the first element, and then do what you need:
`if (found[0] === " ") {
  console.log('Function or method name is not found!')
}`